# MySQL sum hourly usage based on running total

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how much the usage per hour is on the basis of the data below:

```
TIME        DATA
00:00:24    3198
00:17:42    3199
00:44:54    3200
01:24:24    3201
01:52:24    3202
02:27:18    3203
02:51:06    3204
03:28:30    3205
```

When I use a query like:

```
SELECT
    left(TIME,2) AS hour,
    max(DATA) - min(DATA) as usage
    FROM my_table
GROUP BY hour
```

I get incorrect values because MySQL only looks at the minimum value in the hour range compared to the maximum value. The results are:

```
hour     usage
00       2
01       1
02       1
03       0
```

Where if I look at the data manually and sum it by hand I would expect:

```
TIME        DATA    Usage (summed by hand)
00:00:24    3198        
00:17:42    3199        
00:44:54    3200    2 
01:24:24    3201        
01:52:24    3202    3  
02:27:18    3203        
02:51:06    3204    2
03:28:30    3205    1
```

Is there a way to solve this in MySQL directly or do I need to create a loop in PHP?
(edited query and clarified results and expected results)

Comment: Are the results you're posting delivered by the query you quote? I'd expect, whatever else it did, the query above would return four columns. It will be an awful lot easier, and likely more use to you, for us to debug a query that you post rather than guess what you might be using and debug that.

Comment: 01:52:24    3202    3 --- Why?

Comment: Create and post a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   select left(time, 2), count(*) from <your table name> group by left(time, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this solution:

```
SELECT LEFT(time, 2) AS `hour`, COUNT(LEFT(time, 2)) AS `count`
FROM tbl
GROUP BY `hour`
```

You have to replace `tbl` with the name for your table.

Answer (score 0):

Check following query :

```
SELECT A.TIME , A.DATA , CASE WHEN B.USAGE IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE USAGE END AS USAGE
FROM
USAGE AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT LEFT(TIME , 2) AS TIMEINHOUR ,  
MAX(TIME) AS MAXTIME , MAX(DATA) - MIN(DATA) AS USAGE
FROM USAGE
GROUP BY LEFT(TIME , 2)
) AS B ON A.TIME = B.MAXTIME
```